# Как вывести переменную в div? php

Tags: php

Есть файл `txt`, где временно сохраняется строчка. Я хочу получить эту строчку на другой странице, и вывести в class="replace". Как это сделать?

когда заходят на страницу:

```
   <a href="https://site.ru/index.html">Перейти на сайт -></a>

   <script language="php">
        $openFIle = fopen('../public_html/number_logs.txt', 'w');
        $num = '123';
        $write = fwrite($openFIle, $num);
    </script>
```

Сохраняю в `txt` число.

Как теперь мне прочитать и вывести содержимое файла в class="replace"?

```
<a href="tel:" class="replace"></a>
```

Comment: $num = '123';
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo $num;
        echo '</div>';  так вроде бы ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xksp6qlxmrb081/2019-04-20_094627.png - скриншот